# How to prove that sections of family of curves do not exist (exercise 4.7 in Harris' Algebraic Geometry)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In exercise 4.7 of his book *Algebraic Geometry*, Prof. Harris asked to show that there is no local section of the universal hyperplane section of a smooth plane conic or the twisted cubic. The question is about local sections of the projection on the space of hyperplanes, that is to say the dual of respectively $\Bbb{P}^2$ and $\Bbb{P}^3$

**Edit**
More precisely, it is asked to show that, for a conic $X$ for instance, there is no open subset $U$ of $(\Bbb{P}^2)^*$, the space of hyperplanes of $\Bbb{P}^2$, such that there is a regular map from $U$ to $$\Omega_X=\{(x,H)\in X\times (\Bbb{P}^2)^* : x\in H\cap X\}$$ that is section of the second projection of $\Omega_X$ on $(\Bbb{P}^2)^*$

I could not find a proof without using equations and coordinates for the plane conic or the twisted cubic. Is there a less pedestrian & more geometric proof in the spirit of this book ? For instance, Prof. Harris mentioned that this result is an immediate consequence of his Theorem 11.14, which says that the domain of a regular map between projective varieties is irreducible if it has irreducible fibers with constant dimension and an irreducible image. I failed to see why !?

**Edit** Following the comment of Georges, the reference to Theorem 11.14 is just to show that $\Omega_X$ is irreducible

Comment: Just to be sure I am understanding the question, if $X$ is the smooth plane conic, it concerns the local existence of a section of the first projection $\{(x,H) \in \mathbb{P}^2 \times (\mathbb{P}^2)^\vee : x \in H \cap X\} \rightarrow X$?

Comment: @RghtHndSd Sorry about being imprecise ! You are very right to ask for more precision. Prof. Harris is actually asking to prove there is no local section of the second projection if I take your own notations. Following your comment I included this precision in an edit of my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not certain it is clear. Let $H$ be the universal hyperplane section. What does a "local section" mean here? Does it mean for every point $p \in X$, a Zariski open subscheme $U \subset X$ and a morphism $U \rightarrow H$ which is a section of $H \rightarrow X$?

Comment: @RghtHndSd You are right again to ask for more precisions ! (I am using your notations of your first comment to answer your question) It is asked to show that there exist no open subset $U$ of $(\Bbb{P}^2)^*$ for the conic such that there is a section from $U$ to $\Omega_X=\{(x,H)\in \Bbb{P}^2\times (\Bbb{P}^2)^* : x\in H\cap X\}$ (a regular map that gives $1_U$ when composed with the projection on the second factor).

Comment: There are two obvious maps that I see to apply the theorem to. The first is the section $U \rightarrow \Omega_X$, however we know a priori that $U$ is irreducible, so this seems pointless. The other is the map $\Omega_X \rightarrow U$. However the fibers of this map are not irreducible. So I'm with you, I don't see what Joe was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the assertion in the exercise, there **does exist** a regular section of the fibration $\pi_X:\Omega_X\to X$ ( and not only a rational one!).
The variety $\Omega_X$ consists of pairs  $(H,x)$ with  $x\in X$ and $H$ a line $H\subset \mathbb P^2$ passing through $x$ i.e. $x\in H$ .
The projection $\pi_X$ sends such a pair to $x\in X\subset \mathbb P^2$.

A section $s:X\to \Omega_X$ is given by the following construction:
Fix a point $p\in \mathbb P^2\setminus X$ and define $s:X\to \Omega_X$ by $s(x)=(\overline {xp},x)$, where $\overline {xp}$ is the line joining $x$ to $p$.

**Edit**
Since brunoh tells me in his comment  that the problem is about the other projection $\pi _1:\Omega_X\to (\mathbb P^2)^{\star }$, here is why that other projection has no rational section :

The morphism $\pi _1$ is ramified $2$- covering of $(\mathbb P^2)^{\star }$ and a section $s$ of that covering over an open subset $U\subset (\mathbb P^2)^{\star }$ would choose for each line $H\subset \mathbb P^2$ one of the two points of intersection  $H\cap X$ of the line $H$ and the conic $X$.
 Choosing the other point of intersection would yield another section $s'$ of $\pi_2$ and the closures $I,I'$ of the images of those sections $s,s'$ would give a reduction $\Omega_X=I_1\cup I_2$ of the irreducible variety $\Omega_X$, a contradiction.

**New edit**
The situation is crystal-clear geometrically:
If you fix a conic  $X\subset \mathbb P^2$, every line $H\subset \mathbb P^2$ will cut $X$ in two points, except in the rare cases where the line is tangent to the conic, in which case there is only one (double) point.
[*Rare* means that the set of such tangent lines is an algebraic curve in  $(\mathbb P^2)^{\star }$, called the dual conic]
The result we are investigating says that it is impossible for each non-tangent line to *choose in an algebraic way*  one of those two points .

Comment: @Georges_Elencwajg Thank you very much for your answer ! Unfortunately, Prof. Harris is asking to show that there is no section relatively to the other projection (not the one on $X$). I believe he is right for $X$ being a plane conic or the twisted cubic, because I found a proof using equations and coordinates. I just wanted another proof more elegant ...

Comment: Dear brunch, if Harris asks about the other projection, then the exercise is  not formulated  very clearly (and I stand by my geometric solution of the natural interpretation of the problem) And I emphatically suggest  you  post your calculations.

Comment: Ok, I have now posted in an edit a solution to the other interpretation of the exercise too.

Comment: @Georges_Elencwajg Dear Georges, tank you very much for your edit which is exactly the kind of answer I was waiting for ! My solution was so inelegant: I just took a generic conic equation and a generic section, so I had to prove that the system $X(a,b)^2+Y(a,b)^2=Z(a,b)^2$ and $Z(a,b)=a*X(a,b)+b*Y(a,b)$ does not have a solution with homogeneous polynomials of the same degree $d$ in the variables $a$ and $b$. I found it really inelegant compare to your solution, which can also be easily generalized to the twisted cubic. Does it work also for any rational curve $X$ in $\Bbb{P}^n$ ?

Comment: @Georges_Elencwajg I upvoted your answer but before considering it as the definite one, I have one small question: your reasoning is perfect if neither closure of the image of $s$ and $s'$ is not the whole $\Omega_X$. But it is clear for me that a section is always a regular dominant map if $X$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1$. How do you deal with this ? And by the way, my name here is brunoh not brunch (must be an automatic change from the spelling engine ...)

Comment: Dear Brunoh, first let me apologize for deforming your name: my computer screen is not as clean as it should be! I have corrected your name in the answer but, alas, I can't modify my comments. As for your question in your last comment: by possibly restricting the sections $s,s'$ to a smaller open subset $V\subset U\subset (\mathbb P^2)^{\star }$ you will achieve that $s(V), s'(V)$ are disjoint open subsets of $\Omega_X$, which is impossible in an irreducible variety.

Comment: @Georges_Elencwajg Thank you very much for your patience and your last comment that answers all my question  (it is indeed easy to construct by symmetry $s'$ as regular map out of $s$) ! I am validating your answer.

Comment: Hi -- is there a nice way to see that $\Omega_X$ is irreducible? I only know how to do this by explicit computation (very nasty!) or by invoking a semicontinuity theorem in commutative algebra. My concern is that you're sweeping the real difficulty under the rug.

Comment: I posted my comment as a question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621958/irreducibility-of-universal-hyperplane-section

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the nice answer of Georges, I would like to complete it with the other part of the exercise about the twisted cubic, following the same principle than his approach. It seems to me that the key of his answer is that having a local section $s$ of $\Omega_X$ defined on an open set $U$ with image $s(U)$ an open subset of $\Omega_X$, which is a regular map of varieties, we have to be able to build another section defined on the same $U$ with an open image $s'(U)$ disjoint of $s(U)$, and which is also a regular map of varieties. In the case of a generic smooth conic and the particular case of the twisted cubic, this can be done easily because the equations of the variety obey a natural simple symmetry (here changing the sign of one or two of the projective "coordinates"). So from $s$ we can build $s'$ immediately locally, and get a regular map. This also answer my question in one of my comment: this approach can clearly not be easily generalized to other $d$-dimensional curves.