# Irreducibility of universal hyperplane section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056023/how-to-prove-that-sections-of-family-of-curves-do-not-exist-exercise-4-7-in-har), Georges Elencwajg gives a fantastic geometric answer. However, this answer rests on the fact that the universal hyperplane section $\Omega_X$ is irreducible. I only know how to prove this by explicit computation (very nasty -- one splits into affine charts and rationally parameterizes each part) or by invoking a semicontinuity theorem in commutative algebra.

Is there a slicker way to do this?

Comment: The fibers of the projection $\Omega_X \to X$ are $\mathbb{P}^1$'s (the fiber over $x \in X$ is the set of lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$ passing through $x$, which is a $\mathbb{P}^1$). Georges's answer shows that this is Zariski-locally trivial (presumably this is the essential content of your chart-by-chart computation). An alternate approach is the following: a proper map of varieties, with irreducible fibers of a fixed dimension, and irreducible target, must have irreducible source.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is there an easier proof? Consider the map $\Omega_X \to X \times X$ that sends $(x,H) \to (x,y)$, where $y$ is the other point of $H \cap X$. I think this is an isomorphism.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Is there a problem when $H$ is tangent?

Comment: No, it maps to the diagonal of $X \times X$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Typically these incidence correspondences can be realized as projective bundles, from which irreducibility is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 5.8 of Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course* (for arbitrary $X$). The proof given there is elementary.